# Accessing SalesForce account in android

Tags: android, salesforce

Hi friends any body worked on Mobile SDK for android how to access it on android any tutorial please suggest

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Mobile_SDK_for_Android is a great place to start with a tutorial.